# Bind Angular inputs/outputs via data attributes

Tags: angular

Is it possible to bind input and output properties using data attributes?

I'm trying to see if we can use Angular 2+ from within a number a different environments where the html editor strips out unknown tags. So, this `<ng-test [inTest]="test" (outTest)="test()">NG Test</ng-test>` becomes just `<p>NG Test</p>` after the editor processes the code.

The same question would apply to `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` etc. The html editors will strip those away as well.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Editors like CKEDITOR already covered the configuration for allowed content (elements,attributes).
https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that ability, but some systems, such as the Sharepoint Publishing infrastructure, strip the code at the server level, so allowing it in the html editor alone isn't a good enough solution on its own.

Comment: altering content at server side is required to ensure the data/content is having only allowed tags. for example even the h1 or style tag is disabled in editor, i can inspect and inject it, in such cases handling at server side is required